# Unable to upload multiple files or collection of files in mutipart/form-data request using retrofit in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, multipartform-data, retrofit2

I am developing an Android application. In my app, I need to upload multiple or collection of files to server in multipart/form-data request. I am using Retrofit 2 for it. I can upload single file to server. But when I upload list of file, file values are always null at the server side.

This is my retrofit service interface

```
public interface ApiService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("Troll/CreateMemePost")
    Call<ResponseBody> postMeme(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> files, @Part("AuthToken") RequestBody authToken);
}
```

As you can see I am trying to upload list of file as first parameter.

This is how I upload in activity

```
final ArrayList<File> photoFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> files = new ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part>();
        for(Bitmap bitmap: previewBitmaps)
        {
            File file = null;
            try{
                String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpeg";
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
                if(file.exists())
                {
                    file.delete();
                }
                OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
                os.close();
                photoFiles.add(file);
                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);
                MultipartBody.Part partFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("multipart/form-data",file.getName(),requestFile);
                files.add(partFile);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if(files!=null && files.size()>0)
        {
            final Retrofit retrofit = app.getApiClient().getRetrofit();
            ApiService service = app.getApiClient().getApiService();

            RequestBody authToken = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), app.getAuthToken());

            Call<ResponseBody> call = service.postMeme(files,authToken);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if(photoFiles!=null && photoFiles.size()>0)
                    {
                        for(File tempFile : photoFiles)
                        {
                            if(tempFile.exists())
                            {
                                tempFile.delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(response!=null)
                    {
                        if(response.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"File Uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(!response.isSuccessful() && response.errorBody()!=null)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Server error message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            /*try{

                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }*/
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Response is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    if(photoFiles!=null && photoFiles.size()>0)
                    {
                        for(File tempFile : photoFiles)
                        {
                            if(tempFile.exists())
                            {
                                tempFile.delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Unable to transfer data to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

But when I upload, I receive AuthToken field successfully at the server side. But the file values are always null. I am using ASP.NET MVC for backend. You can see the screenshot below. It is always null. U bind like this at server side.

```
public JsonResult CreateMemePost(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files,CreateMemePostModel model)
```

files is always null and AuthToken field in model is present as sent from my app. When I upload single file like this

```
public JsonResult CreateMemePost(HttpPostedFileBase file,CreateMemePostModel model)
```

It is working and uploaded successfully. I am pretty sure that the problem is with my retrofit code. What is wrong with my code? How can I upload list of files to server in multipart/form-data request using retrofit in Android?

I tried this as well to upload files only

```
public interface ApiService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Troll/CreateMemePost")
    Call<ResponseBody> postMeme(@Field("files") ArrayList<RequestBody> files);//, @Part("AuthToken") RequestBody authToken);
}
```

Files count is always 0 at the server side.

Then I tried another solution using MapPart

```
public interface ApiService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("Troll/CreateMemePost")
    Call<ResponseBody> postMeme(@PartMap() Map<String,RequestBody> files, @Part("AuthToken") RequestBody authToken);
}
```

I create map like this in activity

```
 HashMap<String,RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
 // Other steps
 MediaType MEDIA_TYPE=MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data");
 bodyFile = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE,file);
 map.put("files",bodyFile);
```

Files is always null at the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. I used RequestBody and MultipartBody.Builder. I uploaded the solution on Github.

Please have a look at this link - https://github.com/waiyanhein/how-to-upload-multiple-files-using-retrofit-in-android.